# SearchView query resets after returning from Dialog

Tags: java, android, searchview, android-dialogfragment

I have an SearchView and a button in an ActionBar. The button shows a DialogFragment that contains some checkboxes to filter search results. But when I click OK to close the DialogFragment, the SearchView query resets, and I don't know why. This is my code:

`BusquedaActivity.java`:

```java
public class BusquedaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FiltroTemasDialogFragment.FiltroTemasDialogListener {

    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager lm;
    RecursoAdapter ra;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set actionbar
        // Create RecyclerView
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.busqueda, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.acc_buscar);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String cad) {
                buscador(cad);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String cad) { return true; }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.acc_listar:
                FiltroTemasDialogFragment dialogFragment = new FiltroTemasDialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"filtro_temas");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(FiltroTemasDialogFragment dialog) {
        // ...
        buscador(((SearchView) findViewById(R.id.acc_buscar)).getQuery().toString());
    }

    public void buscador(String cad){
        // Search
        ra.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can declare the `SearchView` at the class. Then, you can refer it to get the text.

```
RecyclerView rv;
LinearLayoutManager lm;
RecursoAdapter ra;
private SearchView searchView;
```

Then change your:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
```

To

```
searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
```

After that, at your `onDialogPositiveClick()`. You refer it.

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(FiltroTemasDialogFragment dialog) {
    // ...
    buscador(searchView.getQuery());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer why the query gets reset when the dialog closes and how to resolve it